# Python implementation of ed25519 shared secret agreement

Tags: python-3.x, elliptic-curve, ed25519, shared-secret

Let's consider the following example. Using Python library tinyec I can write the following code:

```
def compress(pubKey):
     return hex(pubKey.x) + hex(pubKey.y % 2)[2:]


curve = registry.get_curve('brainpoolP256r1')
alicePrivKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
alicePubKey = alicePrivKey * curve.g
bobPrivKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
bobPubKey = bobPrivKey * curve.g

print("Now exchange the public keys (e.g. through Internet)")

aliceSharedKey = alicePrivKey * bobPubKey
print("Alice shared key:", compress(aliceSharedKey))

bobSharedKey = bobPrivKey * alicePubKey
```

In this way Alice and Bob are able to derive a shared secret through the Internet. Now, I need to know if I can do the same thing with the ed25519 curve, since I was not able to found any kind of libraries.

So, I am interested in finding a way to do this type of operation safely. How could I do ? What are the best practices for this specific operation?

Thanks

Comment: In the posted code a key agreement is implemented, i.e. ECDH. The Curve 25519 counterpart to ECDH is X25519 and is supported for Python e.g. by [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.html?highlight=x25519#x25519-key-exchange). Ed25519 is the Curve 25519 counterpart to ECDSA, which is used for signing.